# Angular Reactive Forms. Modify data before assigning to form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an Angular reactive form with `event_date` field. I want to modify the data before assigning to form.

For example I have date in format of:

```
Tue Aug 28 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Armenia Standard Time)
```

And I want to modify it with `toLocalString()` before assigning to form.

I have tried to use arrow function instead of default value, but with no result.

```
  tournamentEventForm() : FormGroup{
    return this.fb.group({
      'event_description': '',
      'event_date': (dateString: string)=>{return 'modified string'},
      'event_time': ''
    })
  }
```

Is there any way to do it without onChange listeners and using only formBuilder syntax?

Comment: Is it a date-picker where you can select a date?

Comment: yes, I'm using material date picker

Comment: Check my answer. You can just subscribe to changes on the datepicker and edit the value on the control itself

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

```
dateString.toLocaleString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You add function but need to add value to `event_date`

```
tournamentEventForm() : FormGroup{
  return this.fb.group({
    'event_description': '',
    'event_date': this.getModifiedDate(date),
    'event_time': ''
  })
}

private getModifiedDate(dateString: string):string{
  return 'modified string'
}
```